# How to add a magnifying glass icon in search box?

Tags: reactjs, search, components

```
import React from 'react'

function Search ({ handleInput, search }) {
    return (
        <section className="searchbox-wrap">
            <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Search for a Movie" 
                className="searchbox" 
                onKeyPress={search} 
            />
            
        </section>
    )
}

export default Search
```

```
import React from 'react'

function Search ({ handleInput, search }) {
    return (
        <section className="searchbox-wrap">
            <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Search for a Movie" 
                className="searchbox"
results="0"
 
                onKeyPress={search} 
            />
            
        </section>
    )
}

export default Search
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good at frontend, so I use UI libraries to get these jobs done. You can checkout the search bar component available on the tailwind components website. That has the search bar icon in it. Since it's tailwind, you can customise the other properties as you find suitable.

Here's the link -> https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/search-bar

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).